# Как выполнить Sql-запрос в c#?

Tags: c#

Можно ли выполнять Sql-запрос в C#?
Я где-то видел, что можно.
Если можно, то как?

Comment: вы хоть пытались искать ответ на этот вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=usersdb;Integrated Security=True";
string sqlExpression = "SELECT * FROM Users";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
}
```

Чтобы выполнить команду, необходимо применить один из методов SqlCommand:

ExecuteNonQuery: просто выполняет sql-выражение и возвращает количество измененных записей. Подходит для sql-выражений INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.

ExecuteReader: выполняет sql-выражение и возвращает строки из таблицы. Подходит для sql-выражения SELECT.

ExecuteScalar: выполняет sql-выражение и возвращает одно скалярное значение, например, число. Подходит для sql-выражения SELECT в паре с одной из встроенных функций SQL, как например, Min, Max, Sum, Count.